# how to used requestAction function in ctp file of cakephp 3 .2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

i have used requestAction function in cakephp 3.2 but Not work properly .

when i called in ctp file successfully but not return and  break after used this function.
and skip this function working fine.

Comment: please read it before ask new question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what do you mean by return and break ?? post your question more clearly with some work you did..so that people can help you !

Comment: actually , i have used in cakephp 3.2 when i facing this problem and old version 2.x in working fine .

Comment: Despite your question lacking any reproducable problem description, `requestAction()` is deprecated anyways... use [**view cells**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

RequestAction is no longer included in cakephp, instead you can use cells

[Cakephp 3.X Cells](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)

Comment: try to mention example to make it more clear..rather than trying to post link only.